# IIS addressing a mapped share instead of a UNC path

Tags: iis

I've been asked to resolve a problem for a web application working in tandem with a desktop app.  I can't recode the apps, I can only configure the IIS server to do what the business unit wants.  The desktop app can only use a "relative path" using a mapped drive letter.  The web app has no idea what to do with the mapped drive, it wants a UNC path.

The app pool identity is an AD account with elevated rights, and when I sign into the server as that account, I can see and access the mapped drive.  If I go directly to the resource that is mapped, I have access to everything I need.  I just don't know how to make that mapped drive visible as a server instead of a local drive.

Would creating a DNS named space work for this?  Is there an IIS setting I'm overlooking?  Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it's been years since I ran IIS servers so I'm probably not totally understanding the problem.  However, do these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57148733/iis-application-pool-user-cant-access-unc-drive and https://serverfault.com/questions/279414/permissions-issue-with-virtual-directory-to-unc-path